# Why does my argument matcher fail when I extract it into a variable?

Tags: c#, moq

I'm having a hard time extracting any `It.Is<T>` argument matchers variables. Whenever I do so the test fails.

This works:

```
calculatorMock
    .Setup(x => x.Produce(It.Is<IEnumerable<Report>>(xx => reports.IsEqualTo(xx))))
    .Returns(calculatorInputs);
```

However, this fails:

```
var argumentMatcher = It.Is<IEnumerable<Report>>(xx => reports.IsEqualTo(xx));
calculatorMock
    .Setup(x => x.Produce(argumentMatcher))
    .Returns(calculatorInputs);
```

`IsEqualTo` is a static method returning bool.

The issue is that Moq says `Produce()` was invoked with a null list when I'm expecting it to be called with a list containing 3 items. In this example, `xx` denotes the null list. I'm not sure why I need the argument matcher inline with my Moq verification.

I just found out that the following works:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Report>, bool>> expression = x => reports.IsEqualTo(x);
calculatorMock
    .Setup(x => x.Produce(It.Is(expression)))
    .Returns(calculatorInputs);
```

Is there a specific reason why `It.Is<T>` cannot be extracted like I attempted to do above?

Here is a working copy of the problem:

using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace MoqArgumentMatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testRunner = new TestRunner();

```
        testRunner.Passes();
        testRunner.Fails();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class TestRunner
{
    [Fact]
    public void Passes()
    {
        // Arrange
        var calculatorMock = new Mock<ICalculator>();
        var consumer = new CalculatorConsumer(calculatorMock.Object);
        var report = new Report {Id = 1};

        // Act
        consumer.Consume(report);

        // Assert
        calculatorMock.Verify(x => x.Produce(
            It.Is<Report>(xx => xx.Id == 1)), Times.Once());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Passes2()
    {
        // Arrange
        var calculatorMock = new Mock<ICalculator>();
        var consumer = new CalculatorConsumer(calculatorMock.Object);
        var report = new Report { Id = 1 };

        // Act
        consumer.Consume(report);

        // Assert
        Expression<Func<Report, bool>> expression = x => x.Id == 1;
        calculatorMock.Verify(x => x.Produce(It.Is(expression)), Times.Once());
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Fails()
    {
        // Arrange
        var calculatorMock = new Mock<ICalculator>();
        var consumer = new CalculatorConsumer(calculatorMock.Object);
        var report = new Report {Id = 1};

        // Act
        consumer.Consume(report);

        // Assert
        var argumentMatcher = It.Is<Report>(xx => xx.Id == 1);
        calculatorMock.Verify(x => x.Produce(argumentMatcher), Times.Once());
    }
}

public class CalculatorConsumer
{
    private readonly ICalculator _calculator;

    public CalculatorConsumer(ICalculator calculator)
    {
        _calculator = calculator;
    }

    public void Consume(Report report)
    {
        _calculator.Produce(report);
    }
}

public interface ICalculator
{
    void Produce(Report report);
}

public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: "this fails" is far too vague a description. *How* does it fail?

Comment: @JonSkeet: You're absolutely right. I've added everything I can think of.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program? That would make it easier to test. I suspect it's to do with type inference, but it's hard to say for sure. (It doesn't help that the Moq documentation link doesn't work on the project page!)

Comment: @JustinPihony: Thanks for the suggested answer. It appears to be exactly what I'm running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the `Passes2` and `Fails` tests is most easily understood, to me at least, as a break in the Expression chain in the case of the failing test.

The first thing to note is the signature of `It.Is`:

```
TValue It.Is<TValue>(Expression<Func<TValue, bool>> match)
```

In particular, note that when it is executed, it returns an instance of `TValue`, not an `Expression`. The next thing to note is the signature of `Verify` expects an `Expression` (of type `Action` or `Func`) in which one is to call the required method.

When Moq executes the `Verify` method, it looks at the expression and extracts the method call it is verifying then the parts of the expression that are supplying values for the method being called, in this case the `report` argument in `Produce(Report report)`. It then compiles this small parameter-expression-sub-tree to execute against the value that was used to call the `Produce` method to determine if it's a match.

In the case of the Passes and Passes2, it is able to extract an `Expression<Func<Report, bool>>`. The compiler knows that it is supposed to be parsing the code into an expression so creates an expression tree for the `It.Is` call.

In the case of `Fails`, on this line...

```
var argumentMatcher = It.Is<Report>(xx => xx.Id == 1);
```

...the compiler sees a call to `It.Is` that is going to be evaluated as soon as the code is run. It therefore determines that the type of `var` is going to be `TValue` (the return type), not an `Expression` of anything. Thus when `argumentMatcher` is seen inside the `Verify` call it is now a leaf node in the expression tree, a simple variable.

At run time, `argumentMatcher` is probably evaluated as `null`. Moq, seeing that the parameter-expression-sub-tree is a value and not a `Func`, performs a comparison against the value, being `null`, rather than executing the comparison against `1` as desired.

(This is in the spirit of answering open questions despite the OP being satisfied with an answer on another question!)

Comment: This is an awesome answer! Thank you very much for providing an incredibly deep answer.