# Moq - It.Is parameter being evaluated as null

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I'm trying to clean up my unit tests by implementing [this pattern](https://medium.com/@martinrybak/a-cleaner-way-to-create-mocks-in-net-6e039c3d1db0). Unfortunately, I'm having a problem with my setups, if I try to use It.Is in the matching, so:

```
public class MockEmployeeExclusionRulesService : Mock<IEmployeeExclusionRulesService>
{
    public MockEmployeeExclusionRulesService MockIsEmployeeExcludedFromSubmissionAsync(FpsFileContentEmployee fpsFileContentEmployee, bool output)
    {
        Setup(x => x.IsEmployeeExcludedFromSubmissionAsync(fpsFileContentEmployee))
            .ReturnsAsync(output);
        return this;
    }
}
```

```
_employeeExclusionRulesServiceMock.MockIsEmployeeExcludedFromSubmissionAsync(
    It.Is<FpsFileContentEmployee>(y =>
        y.FpsId == _fpsId &&
        y.PersonOnPayrollId == _personOnPayrollId),
    output: excludeFromSubmission);
```

When I step through the code, I've found that in the Setup method, `fpsFileContentEmployee` is `null`. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373406/2182594) which I think explains what's going on, but I'm not sure what they mean by "make it an expression typed variable" - what am I making an expression and how do I use it?

---

Attempt at a minimal reproducible example:

```
public class InputClass
{
    public string Foo {get; set;}
    public string Bar {get; set;}
}
```

```
public interface IMockClass
{
    bool DoTheThing(InputClass inputClass);
}
```

```
public class MockMockClass : Mock<IMockClass>
{
    public MockMockClass MockDoTheThing(InputClass inputClass, bool output)
    {
        Setup(x => x.DoTheThing(inputClass))
            .Returns(output);
        return this;
    }
}
```

```
[TestFixture]
public class AllTheTests
{
    private readonly MockMockClass _mockClassMock = new ();

    [Test]
    public void DoTheThingTest()
    {
        _mockClassMock.MockDoTheThing(
            It.Is<InputClass>(x =>
                x.Foo == "spam"),
            output: true);
    }
}
```

I believe that if you debug the test and step through line by line, you'll find that when it gets into `MockMockClass.MockDoTheThing()`, `inputClass` will be `null`.

---

EDIT: It looks like the problem is trying to assign `It.is` to a variable - the situation is described further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576329/why-does-my-argument-matcher-fail-when-i-extract-it-into-a-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1). Unfortunately, with the pattern I'm using that's fairly unavoidable, so I need to figure out a workaround.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a workaround by creating an overload that takes an expression, like this:

```
public class MockMockClass : Mock<IMockClass>
{
    public MockMockClass MockDoTheThing(InputClass inputClass, bool output)
    {
        Setup(x => x.DoTheThing(inputClass))
            .Returns(output);
        return this;
    }

    public MockMockClass MockDoTheThing(Expression<Func<InputClass, bool>> inputClassMatch, bool output)
    {
        Setup(x => x.DoTheThing(It.Is(inputClassMatch)))
            .Returns(output);
        return this;
    }
}
```

```
[TestFixture]
public class AllTheTests
{
    private readonly MockMockClass _mockClassMock = new ();

    [Test]
    public void DoTheThingTest()
    {
        _mockClassMock.MockDoTheThing(x =>
                x.Foo == "spam",
            output: true);
    }
}
```

It's not my favourite solution, but it seems to work.